# Render text in purely native Android app

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have a purely native Android NDK app, and need to render some text at every frame. I have read posts saying that I need to create a single image file with all the characters of my font, and then render each character as a quad from this image. This sounds like a lot of work and I don't know where to obtain such an image file for a simple font, like Arial. Is there an alternative, easier approach to drawing text in a purely native Android app?

Or, where can I retrieve such an image file to make my own font renderer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to see if you can integrate a font renderer into your app. [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) is a popular one that is written in pure C with no external dependencies which make it easy to use. [OGLFT](http://oglft.sourceforge.net/) is a version of FreeType that renders to OpenGL. I would do a little more research to see if there are alternatives that may be a better fit but these seem to be pretty good.

[This](http://davidpetrie.com/?p=275) seems to be even better.

Comment: Unfortunately FTGLES only supports iOS devices at the moment, and FreeType's licensing policy doesn't permit me to use this.

Comment: Just curious, what part of FreeType's license doesn't work for you?

Comment: It turns out I may be able to use it afterall. Thanks!

Comment: Just to inform. [Freetype license](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/license.html) (BSD + author crediting) or GPL2.