# Adding native language android

Tags: android, fonts, fontconfig

I need to add native language rendering (not the font.My language,sinhala,use complex scripts) support to android.Is there any chance of using `fontconfig` compiled for arm to do this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.I wanna know is there any possibility before start.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165097/render-text-in-purely-native-android-app

Comment: If you want to add support for your language to Android system, then it is a hard task. If you want to add it to your app, you can use anything available to you.

Comment: I alrady know how to build apps with language support.But I need the language support system wide.